# diference between RTOS and OS?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, design

I am confused between real time operating systems and normal operating systems(windows etc). and please tell me android is rtos or os.
suggest some good books for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Comment: There exist RT versions of Windows and Linux. I guess the counterpart is optimized of eg. (G)UI experience.

Comment: *Finally* someone comes up with this question instead of just calling every task scheduler an RTOS :) +1 -- Yet, Nick Alexeev is right. Searching for "RTOS" will quickly yield http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system which explains a lot of it.

Comment: @jippie: You need to be careful with the use of the phrase RT in conjunction with Windows. Windows RT is the ARM version of Windows 8 and by no means a real-time operating system. A real-time (able) version of Windows would be Windows Compact Embedded. I'm pretty sure you are aware of that, but let's not confuse the TO.

Comment: @TomL. I meant to state there is actually a version of Windows sold as 'Real Time'. As in RTOS. You won't find it in your average retail store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main characteristic for a RTOS is that it is basically able to meet your deadline. Whatever that deadline is, that is all up to you.

Imagine a braking system: The 'moment' I step on the pedal, I would like the car to brake. I do not want to draw one more frame of the navigation display or to update the speedometer.

Real-Time does NOT mean, that everything has to be very fast, but it says that an event must be handled within a specific time (again, the timeframe is up to you; can be years as well).

There is often a distinction between hard and soft realtime systems. I always thought of the following situation:
Hard-Realtime: The brake must work within 1/10 of a second, whenever the event (brake pedal applied) appears. Otherwise: Catastrophic Failure will be imminent (worst case: crash into another car; drive down a bridge, ...)
Soft-Realtime: I want the navigation display to update as often as possible; if it cannot do that it's not a big deal, the next frame will come anyway - the already calculated data will be useless though and gets discarded.
Non-Realtime: I have no way of saying that an event will cause some action in the near future. The brake might work, the navigation system might work, but I cannot guarantee that the brake will immediately function (it might do so 10 seconds later because the single CPU was doing ... other ... things in the meanwhile).

Usually there is some sort of priority control in RTOSes. They can be event driven (with certain events having a higher priority than others) or time driven (every sub-system gets it's share of time, no matter if it needs it or not).

There can also be systems which are basically RTOSes and handle some events in a real-time way and others just like a normal OS would.